# Quais as vantagens de usar "currying" em uma função?

Tags: terminologia, sintaxe, programação-funcional

Entendo que, simplificando rudemente, usar currying é quebrar uma função que recebe vários argumentos em funções menores que recebem apenas partes dos argumentos da função original. Considere o código abaixo como exemplo:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  //função de somar com a sintaxe comum
  console.log("Função comum: " + soma(1,1));
  //função de somar com a sintaxe "currificada"
  console.log("Função com curry: " + somacurry(2)(2));
  //função que exibe as informações da pessoa também com curry
  console.log(pessoa("Artur")("Trapp")("21"));
}

function soma(a,b) { return a + b; }

function somacurry(a){
  return function (b) { return a + b; }
}

function pessoa(nome){
  return function (sobrenome){
    return function (idade) {
      return "Olá, meu nome é " + nome + " " + sobrenome + ", e eu tenho " + idade + " anos!";
    }
  }
}
```

Sei que essa técnica é bastante usada em linguagens funcionais (como Haskell). Mas não sou capaz de enxergar vantagens, sejam elas em simplificar a sintaxe ou em performance. Quais seriam as vantagens de usar uma função com a técnica de currying, no lugar de funções com sintaxe comum?

PS: Não achei tags ideais

Answer (score 0):

Currying é uma técnica para reescrita de funções com múltiplos parâmetros como a composição de funções de um parâmetro. A função do tipo curry pode ser aplicada apenas a um subconjunto de seus parâmetros. O resultado é uma função onde os parâmetros neste subconjunto são agora fixados como constantes, e os valores do resto dos parâmetros ainda não são especificados. Esta nova função pode ser aplicada aos parâmetros restantes para obter o valor da função final. Por exemplo, uma função adiciona(x,y) = x + y pode ser do tipo curry de forma que o valor de retorno adiciona(2) — note que não há um parâmetro y — será uma função anônima, o que é equivalente à função adiciona2(y) = 2 + y. Esta nova função tem apenas um parâmetro e corresponde a adicionar 2 a um número. Novamente, isso é apenas possível porque as funções são tratadas como valores de primeira importância.

É mais voltada a programação funcional onde qualquer simplificação de sintaxe é bem vinda, embora linguagens como JavaScript também contém com esse recurso, porém nunca vi um exemplo de aplicação fora do escopo do aprendizado deste.

Segundo a [wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

> A motivação prática da técnica é que frequentemente se utiliza funções
>   obtidas através da aplicação de somente alguns dos parâmetros. Algumas
>   linguagens de programação possuem suporte sintático nativo ao
>   currying, de forma que funções com múltiplos parâmetros são expandidas
>   para formas reduzidas; exemplos incluem ML e Haskell. Qualquer
>   linguagem que suporte closures pode ser usada para escrever funções
>   com essa técnica de currying.